# Placing n Queens on n x n board

Tags: chess

**This problem is known as *n* queens puzzle:**  How can we distribute *n* queens on a chess grid of *n* $\times$ *n* so that no queen can threaten another.

Many solutions are possible for *n* > 4.  To answer this question, show a single solution for n from 4 to 10 as well as an algorithm for where to place the queens.

---

- Here is a solution when *n* = 8

> [image: 8 x 8 solution]

Comment: You can simply specify that solutions are to be simple algorithms and not require brute force approaches (i.e. be possible to implement with pen paper)

Comment: it goes without saying :)

Comment: I do think you should clarify whether you mean how many ways it can be done, or if you want an algorithm that can provide just one solution in each case.

Comment: i want (x,y) coordinates of each queen in n*n grid where noone is on the others target ; according of n of course.

Comment: @Meelo it doesnt work .... if u remove queens in extreme right and top , u ll end up with 6 queens in a 7*7 grid and it is nt optimal .... good step just think ahead ...

Comment: I made the post look nicer, I hope you don't mind :D

Comment: had i bothered to put this problem forward to be less reputed ?

Comment: OMG noone seems to be interested in solutions :(

Comment: This is a well known problem for $8 \times 8$, which has [12 different solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) if rotations and reflections are considered identical.  The one you post has a nice pattern, but not all do. It is not clear what the question is.

Comment: the question is considered for n*n chessboard , find each queen s position according to n

Comment: Can you provide just one from those many solutions ? oh boy !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single solutions are shown below for **values of n from 4 to 10**.  Placement of the queens is based on the algorithm described in the Wikipedia page for the **[eight queens puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle)** which is:

> "Let (i, j) be the square in column i and row j on the n × n chessboard, k an integer.
>
> 1. If n is even and n ≠ 6k + 2, then place queens at (i, 2i) and (n/2 + i, 2i - 1) for i = 1,2,...,n/2.
> 2. If n is even and n ≠ 6k, then place queens at (i, 1 + (2i + n/2 - 3 (mod n))) and (n + 1 - i, n - (2i + n/2 - 3 (mod n))) for i = 1,2,...,n/2.
> 3. If n is odd, then use one of the patterns above for (n - 1) and add a queen at (n, n)."

[image: Chess4to7]
[image: Chess8to10]

Comment: yes this s the most optimal solution with the least complexity O(1) . good job .